# Definition from Character Theory

Tags: definition, characters

I have been reading a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2014-142-09/S0002-9939-2014-12050-8/home.html) regarding some relations on character degrees. There is a term being used in the proof of a theorem which is not defined. Neither have I been able to find it in any book about representation theory that I have looked at.

I am quoting a part of the proof:
"$\chi \in$ Irr($G$) lies over $1_{HN}$ then $\chi$ lies over $1_G$". I am not sure what is meant by 'lies over' in this case

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of $G$ and let $\vartheta$ be an irreducible character of $H$. The character $\chi$ is said to lie over $\vartheta$, if $\chi$ is an irreducible constituent of $\vartheta^G$. By the Frobenius reciprocity this is equivalent to say that $\vartheta$ is a constituent of $\chi_N$. In this case, we also say that $\vartheta$ lies under $\chi$.

Comment: This would also be what I understand by it, but that is not consistent with the usage the OP mentions.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Probably the right quote is "if $\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)$ lies over $1_{HN}$, then $\chi$ lies over $1_H$".